# OnClick listener conflict for RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a RecyclerView with a grid list of item, which looks like below. Initially every grid item is INVISIBLE and clicking on its area will make it VISIBLE.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        show()
    }
}
```

Also, a grid item has a BUTTON and clicking on it will direct user to another screen. However, the button's onClick listener is not triggered when clicking on it. Instead, its underneath view holder's itemView's onClick listener is invoked (i.e., the red item will show). I think this is due to the overlapping area of the two items. However, the design needs to be kept and any idea of how to solve this issue?

Below is the layout defined for view item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"       
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_image_view"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_edit"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/edit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:text="@string/edit_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly could you share your xml layout file of the list item. It might help us to narrow down the cause

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul the xml layout file was attached.

Comment: can u put some code here? I couldn't quite understand what u r trying to achieve

Comment: You might want to have the parent View intercept touches and then use some logic to determine which item bounds to check for hits in and subsequently propagate the touch events to. Or if you can, just define the black box after the red box in the layout (in a higher z layer) so it receives the touch events at their overlap points.

Comment: @rookiedev, I believe there is no button in your xml layout. Could you let me know which one you are referring to as button